# Connected scatterplot - How to connect dots in the order desired other than by the x-axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm looking to create a connected scatterplot in `ggplot2` similar in spirit to the chart below.

[image]

The problem is that I can't figure out how to connect the dots by year. By default, `ggplot2` connects them across the x-axis.

Some data for illustration:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(year = 2010:2018)
df$x <- rnorm(9)
df$y <- rnorm(9)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y, group = 1, label = year, alpha = year)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line() +
  geom_text(show.legend = FALSE, nudge_y = -0.05) +
  scale_alpha(range = c(0.4, 1))
```

This gives me this chart:

[image]

I figure the issue is with the `group` argument, but I don't know what else to use other than "1". Anything else doesn't draw the line and gives the feedback

> "geom_path: Each group consists of only one observation. Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?"

Comment: You need `geom_path()` instead of `geom_line()`.

Comment: This worked just fine for me when I replaced `geom_line()` with `geom_path()`  Tested with `ggplot2_3.1.0`. What version are you using?

Comment: head -> desk - I wasn't thinking of geom_path. Thanks.

Comment: yes it is, but there was nothing in that question calling it a "connected scatterplot" which is why it didn't show up in my search.

Comment: @Phil, no problem. Future searchers will your question and get redirected to the linked duplicate.